# using LDAP url in JBOSS oracle-ds.xml

Tags: oracle, jboss, ldap, connection-pooling

Our oracle servers are migrating to `LDAP`. I use `JBOSS` connection pooling in my application which looks like

```
<local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>OracleDB</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbs1:1521:SID</connection-url>
    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
    <user-name>osuser</user-name>
    <password></password>
</local-tx-datasource>
```

Now my DBA gave me a fully qualified LDAP url for the databse that is like server.db.company.com. Can you please suggest how do  I use this url in the `oracle-ds.xml`?

**P.S.** I have already tried the URL as `jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://server.db.company.com.` It gives `invalid LDAP`exception.`